# Dichotomy to find unkown number with success/fail instead of more or less

Tags: python, random, algebra, linden-scripting-language

I'm trying to translate a program from Python to LSL (SecondLife scripting) to find a number I can't access from functions. This number is my linden balance (the money in game.) 
The only way I can determinate that amount from my script is by transferring amounts of money to myself and to check if the paiement was successful or not.

In order to do so, I found a dychotomy python script that works perfectly :

```
from random import randint

n = 100000000 # Maximum amount possible
amountToFind = randint(1,n)
a = 1
b = n
nbAnswers = 0

while b-a >=0: 
    answer= (a+b)//2
    nbAnswers += 1
    if answer== amountToFind:
        print("The correct answer is:", answer)
        break 
    elif answer> amountToFind:
        b = answer- 1
    else:
        a = answer+ 1

print("The number of steps to get the correct amount was :", nbAnswers)
print(amountToFind)
```

The problem is that I can't compare `answer`to the number i'm looking for. I only have fail and success :

```
llCheckLindenBalance()
{
        rep = (a+b)/2;
        transactionId = llTransferLindenDollars(owner, rep);
}

touch_start(integer total_number)
{
    llCheckLindenBalance();
}

transaction_result(key id, integer success, string data)
{
    if(id != transactionId)
        return;



    if(success) // rep < amount or rep == amount
    {

        a = rep+1;
        llOwnerSay("Last amount " +(string)rep);
        llCheckLindenBalance();

    }
    else // FAIL - rep < amount
    {
       b = rep-1;
       llCheckLindenBalance();
    }
}
```

That script works so far, but it will never stop as it nevers knows when to stop. I was thinking about comparing `a` and `b` but the space between them is variable as well (from 0 to 10). So i'm stuck at it. 
I thought about testing `answer+1` and if it fail it means it's the highest amount but I can't now where to test it.

Do you guys have any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Doing things this way is no faster than counting up from 0 and checking every possible value; every iteration will only reduce the bounds by one.  More importantly, llTransferLindenDollars is rate-limited to 1 per second so you'd sooner hit the limit than find any useful result anyway.  Assuming someone has L$20, if you used the Python script and started with L$100,000,000, it would take over three years for the routine to complete.

So, since most SL users do not have L$50,000,000, it would probably be faster to just count from zero and keep checking until a failure is obtained:

```
integer amount;
key trans_id;

default
{
    touch_start(integer total_number)
    {
        amount = 0;
        trans_id = llTransferLindenDollars(llGetOwner(), amount);
    }
    transaction_result(key id, integer success, string data)
    {
        if (id != trans_id) return;
        if (success)
        {
            llOwnerSay("Last amount: " + (string)amount);
            llSleep(1.0); // avoid rate limiting
            trans_id = llTransferLindenDollars(llGetOwner(), ++amount);
        }
        else if (data == "LINDENDOLLAR_INSUFFICIENTFUNDS")
        { // this is the error we care about
            llOwnerSay("L$ balance: " + (string)(amount - 1));
        }
        else
        { // some other error
            llOwnerSay("Error: " + data);
            llSleep(10.0); // wait and retry
            trans_id = llTransferLindenDollars(llGetOwner(), amount);
        }
    }
}
```

This is still incredibly slow and practically useless for anyone with more than a few L$, in part for security reasons - scripts knowing an account's balance would mean that it could drain the entire account instantly without an error.  There is simply no quick way to determine an account's L$ balance unless the account is a bot and whatever bot service you use has an API function that can do that.

Also FYI, it's poor practice to precede user-defined functions with "ll"; the "ll" functions should only be the built-in ones, for readability's sake.